# CakePHP not finding all fields in table, even after model cache deleted

Tags: mysql, cakephp

So my app is running in development mode in one place and in production mode on its live server.  I've just put some changes live and a field that has been in the production DB (MySQL) for a good week or two is not being found by a call to `Model::read()`.  Here's the code, verbatim:

```
    $this->Order->id = $id;
    $created = $this->Order->field('created');
    $this->Order->contain(array('User', 'OrderStatusChange', 'Cart' => array('CartItem' => array('conditions' => array('deleted_date' => null, 'created <=' => $created)))));
    $this->request->data = $order = $this->Order->read();
```

Same code in dev environment returns all fields.  The new(ish) field is missing in production.  I have deleted every file in /app/tmp/cache/models and it has not fixed the problem.  The production site has `Configure::write('debug', 0)`, development site is set to 2.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you already cleared your caches, but problem still exists. So, I will point out one things here:

`$this->Order->contain(...)` here you're using `contain()` and for `contain()`, need to attach `Containable` behavior to model. Your code doesn't clarify that you attach that or not. If not, then  I will suggest you to attach that like:

```
.....
$this->Order->Behaviors->attach('Containable');  // attach Containable behavior
$this->Order->contain(...);
......
```